# get distinct record from table using rowid, rownum from Table

Tags: mysql

I've faced one question that get distinct records from a table without using function like rownum, rowid etc.

I answered that we can do by union by putting inner join in inner query and uion with outer query. I think I gave wrong answer. Any one can tell this approach can get the distinct record from a table or * I gave 100% wrong answer.

Comment: use `DISTINCT` function, see more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: @safinchacko,sagi...I don't have code...That was a question verbally and I gave the answer verbally using logic have written in my question. Just need to ask whether my approach is right or wrong. Can we achieve like I said in my answer ?